# Vanquiser's seal & Bone fist

Tags: dark-souls-2

Does the (bonus) damage damage of Vanquiser's seal apply to the Bone fist?
Quote:

> Increases bare handed attack power.
>   This ring increases the base damage of unarmed fists to 200

Is it possible to dual wield a bone fist with an empty hand (and still get the Vanquiser's seal bonus damage) ?

> Main-Hand:
>
> - Empty (fist)
>
> Off-Hand:
>
> - Bone fist

---

Note: I've yet to find a Bone fist, so I cannot try it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to dual wield weapons you must:

- have two of the same weapon type (fist weapon, sword, axe etc)
- have the required amount of stats (double the base requirement)

While yes, the bone fist is a fist weapon, and with the use of the Vanquishers Seal, your fists are technically fist weapons as well, these cannot be dual wielded together. I.e, you can't dual wield a bone fist and a bare fist.

However (if this is what you're asking) you *can* dual wield two bone fists (with the required stats).

Comment: Ok, so my first guess was correct then. No, unfortunately you can't "dual wield" a bone fist and a bare fist (empty hand)

Comment: Damm, I hoped you could. Do you know if the Vanquiser's seal bonus damage is also applied to the bone fists?

Comment: Again, unfortunately no. That is only for the use of the bare fists.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, ring wont up the damage for the bone fist because its a weapon, but bone fist power stance can be used with it in offhand. However you wont be able to use the ranged l2 fireball unless it is in main hand.

Answer (score -1):

ignore the top comment, i think he never use fist weapon and only using blind guessing.

To be able to use bone fist power stance, you can pair it with any fist weapon (cestus,claw, and vanquisher are doable, i didn't try with other weapon since both are the same weapon type.

Interesting fact that if you pair any fist weapon with vanquisher offhand, your powerstance damage will be increased quite high comparing to other paired fist weapon.

Comment: Directly from the [wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Vanquisher%27s+Seal): "Does NOT work with caestus or claws of any sort." Where are you getting the idea that you can?